# Storybook can't find module '@reach/router'. But gatsby is working fine

Tags: reactjs, storybook

Getting the error

`Storybook can't find module '@reach/router'.` Gatsby is working fine.

```
import * as React from "react";

import { useLocation } from "@reach/router";



const Header = () => {

    const { pathname } = useLocation();
    const isCheckoutHeader = pathname.includes("quote-process");
    return (
        <>
         <div>code here</div>
       </>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: Try remove your `node_modules` and `package.lock` file. Run a fresh install and see that everything gets installed correctly. You could also try downgrading storybook. What errors are you getting when you try run storybook from the console?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever figure this out? Removing `node_modules` didn't seem to help

Answer (score 2):

With Gatsby v4 you'll need to remap `@reach/router` to `@gatsbyjs/reach-router`. If using Storybook v6 and Webpack5 you can use the [NormalModuleReplacementPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/) to perform this remapping.

This assumes your setup is similar to the one explained in the Gatsby docs: [Visual Testing with Storybook](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/testing/visual-testing-with-storybook/).

```
// .storybook/main.js
const webpack = require("webpack")

module.exports = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
  ],
  framework: "@storybook/react",
  core: {
    builder: "@storybook/builder-webpack5",
  },
  staticDirs: ["../public", "../static"],
  webpackFinal: async config => {
    // Transpile Gatsby module because Gatsby includes un-transpiled ES6 code.
    config.module.rules[0].exclude = [/node_modules\/(?!(gatsby)\/)/]
    // Use babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries to remove static queries from components when rendering in storybook
    config.module.rules[0].use[0].options.plugins.push(
      require.resolve("babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries"),
    )
    // remap @reach/router to fork included in Gatsby
    config.plugins.push(
      new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /^@reach\/router/,
        "@gatsbyjs/reach-router",
      ),
    )
    return config
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the purpose of Storybook is made to see the components and not for routing between the pages.